# svn: 'pre-commit' hook failed with error output:

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, mylyn, helios

Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: 'pre-commit' hook failed with error output:
**

I am trying to commit 2 jsp files from Eclips Helios.Its updated with lates Subversion updated verison & mylyn.
Scratched google but nothing found.
However this issue is only coming with some of comments but I can commit the file using other comments and some file can't.
Only output given by the SVN commit is this.

Any help appriciated.
Thanks in advance.
Screen Shot Attached Below

[image: SVN ERROR]

Comment: Can you show your pre-commit hook script?

Comment: where it resides.I dont know.Can u please put the path

Comment: You will find the hook scripts in the hooks folder in your repository (e.g. \\192.168.1.1\svn\projects\hooks)

Comment: Actually I don't have to access to the repository path.SO I am unable to fetch the hook script. Any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible workaround, if you really don't have access to the hooks dir:
Try to sync your changed files with the original (repository-stored ones) files, and find such differences that should be protected by hook scripts:

- jsp contains accented or non-supported special chars (try this first)
- jsp contains illegal whitespace chars

etc. If you find some suspicious, remove it and commit the rest of the changes.

Comment: As I already mensioned here , I am not able to commit using a perticular JIRA id , i fI use different one then its working.I can commit files but if commit the files using same JIRA ID again and again then this errors comes.